# execute action on workflow transition

Tags: 8, workflows

I want to execute PHP script in my custom module, when transition occurs. Workflow is assigned to custom entity. I'm using Drupal's core modules [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/workflows/overview) and [Content moderation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/content-moderation). How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update to achieve this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
*/

function mymodule_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

    //Get the current Moderation state;
    if (isset($entity->moderation_state) && isset($entity->moderation_state->getValue()[0]['target_id'])) {
        $currentState = $entity->hasField('moderation_state') ? $entity->moderation_state->getValue()[0]['target_id'] : null;
    }
    //Get the original Moderation state;
    if ( isset($entity->original->moderation_state ) && isset($entity->original->moderation_state->getValue()[0]['target_id']) ) {
        $originalState = $entity->original !== NULL ? $entity->original->moderation_state->getValue()[0]['target_id'] : null;
    }

    #Get the Transition;
    $workflowTransition = rtrim($originalState.'-->'.$currentState);

    switch ($workflowTransition) {
       case 'published-->needs_review':
       case 'draft-->needs_review':
       //Do something.
      break;
       case 'draft-->needs_review':
      //Do something else;
      break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if ($workflowTransition) {` this will always be true no matter what, because it's set to a string on the line above.

Comment: Yes, you will need to compare states and provide your logic as needed. Look at the updated example.

Comment: I am shocked to learn there are no event emitters for this. But after some searching around I found the request for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2873287. Hopefully we can use those in the near future :)

Comment: It seems like workaround, but it works. :)

Comment: Where does this script live?  In the Content Moderation directory?

Comment: In your custom module.

Comment: I was pretty sure I could do this with entity_update hook but wanted to try to do it the right way with an EventSubscriber. Spent 2 hours trying to find what the event was that is generated by the Content Moderation module.. and eventually ended here.. Ughh!! Why are we ready to release D9 when 8 is barely ready for prime time? lol.

Comment: Thanks for the code. In a general sense it is indeed a disappointment you can't subscribe in a more "proper" way (without contrib).